# adding run time on my java program

Tags: java

what is the correct code to calculating time in Java with
 public static int getGcd( int a, int b, int temp) format?

Comment: `getGcd()`? That sounds mathematical, not chronological...

Comment: Are you wanting the time it takes to calculate GCD? Your question is not clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need help in my program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362739/i-need-help-in-my-program)

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution:

First, Grab and store the time before you start the piece of code you want the run time for:

`long start =System.currentTimeMillis();`

After the code that you are tracking grab the current time and subtract it from your starting point to get the total time elapsed:
`System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);`

Answer (score 0):

If it runs relatively fast and you're trying to get an average time by running it on a bunch of random inputs, use:

```
long totalTime = 0;
long start = System.nanoTime();
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    //Generate a and b
    getGcd(a, b);
}
long end = System.nanoTime();
totalTime = end - start;
start = System.nanoTime();
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    //Generate a and b
}
end = System.nanoTime();
totalTime -= end - start;
return totalTime / n;
```

This gives you your average time in nanoseconds.

Finding the average running time of GCD is a very interesting and complex problem.  In the worst case, the inputs have a ratio which is close to the golden mean (such as consecutive Fibonacci numbers) and then the running time is O(log n).  But it's still possible to have extremely large inputs and end up with essentially constant time.  I'd be curious to know your results.