# I need help in my program

Tags: java, profiling

I have this program in Java import java.util.*;

```
public class Euclid {

    private static final String EXCEPTION_MSG = 
        "Invalid value (%d); only positive integers are allowed. ";

    public static int getGcd( int a, int b)
        {
            if (a < 0)
               {
                   throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(EXCEPTION_MSG, a));
               }
                else 
                    if (b < 0) 
                    { 
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(EXCEPTION_MSG, b));
                    }

            while (b != 0)
            {


                if (a > b) 
                    {
                    a = a - b;
                           }      
                 else 
                   {
                      b   = b - a;
                    }    
            }
              return a;
        }
    }
```

---

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class EuclidGui
{ 
  private static final String PROMPT_A = "#1";
  private static final String PROMPT_B = "#2";
  private static final String BUTTON_TEXT = "Get GCD >>";
  private static final String EXCEPTION_TITLE = "Input Exception";
  private static final String INSTRUCTIONS =    "Type to integer and press 'Get GCD'";
  private static final String DIALOG_TITLE = "Euclid's Algorithm";
  private static final int FIELD_WIDTH = 6;

public static void main (String[] args)
{
final JTextField valueA = new JTextField (FIELD_WIDTH);
final JTextField valueB = new JTextField (FIELD_WIDTH);
final JTextField valueGcd = new JTextField (FIELD_WIDTH);
JLabel labelA = new JLabel(PROMPT_A);
JLabel labelB = new JLabel(PROMPT_B);
JButton computeButton = new JButton(BUTTON_TEXT);
Object[] options = new Object[] {labelA, valueA, labelB, valueB, computeButton, valueGcd};
valueGcd.setEditable (false);
computeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    { try
        { 
           int a = Integer.parseInt(valueA.getText());
           int b = Integer.parseInt(valueB.getText());
           int gcd = Euclid.getGcd(a , b);

           valueGcd.setText(Integer.toString(gcd));
         } 
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), EXCEPTION_TITLE, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

         }
        }
    });
    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, INSTRUCTIONS, DIALOG_TITLE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
    null, options, null);
}      
}
```

and I want to add calculation time code on it but I have no Idea how, and what is the correct code that I use.Please help me if any one have an Idea.

Comment: Please indent all the code so it all shows up as code.

Comment: What do you mean under ' time code'

Answer (score 2):

[System.currentTimeMillis()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) would do the trick:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// do stuff
long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

Comment: This is correct in principle, but for the OP's particular case it probably won't work; see my answer.

Comment: Stephen is absolutely correct, that was a rather glaring oversight on my part. FWIW I wouldn't bother with nanoTime ever, because of the issues you pointed out with it. Milliseconds and a huge loop is the way forward!

Answer (score 1):

The chances are that a single call to `getGcd` will take so little time that you will have difficulty measuring it reliable and accurately.

The [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) method will give you the wall clock time measured in milliseconds.  However, the granularity of the millisecond clock is probably too coarse.  (Read the javadoc!).

The [`System.nanoTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) method gives a system time with (as the javadoc says) *"nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond accuracy."*.

There are also issues with `nanoTime()` on multicore machines with some operating systems.  For instance, I've heard that different cores can have independent nanoTime clocks that can drift with respect to each other.  This can result in `System.nanoTime()` returning values that are non-monotonic; e.g. if the current thread is rescheduled by the OS to run on a different core between two `nanoTime()` calls.

If I was doing this, I'd put the calls to `getGcd()` into a loop that ran it 10,000 or 100,000 times, measure the time for the loop, and divide the measured time by the relevant factor.